Can 反応する mean 'To cause a reaction'?
I came across this sentence in Konosuba vol 3 by Natsume Akatsuki (chapter 1 part 7).

魔道具での取り調べ結果を証拠にするというのなら、今こうして、俺の言葉が魔道具に反応していないのもまた証拠になる。

Context:
The main character is being tried for treason. Before the trial, the prosecutor interrogated him using a magical lie detector which looks like a bell and reacts to lies by ringing. The bell is present again during the trial, and at some point he says something that proves he's innocent since the bell doesn't ring.
I'd assume from context that the bolded part means that the device didn't react, but since 言葉 is marked with が it sounds like his words didn't react to the device, which doesn't make sense to me.
I'd expect the sentence to be 魔道具が俺の言葉に反応していない instead.
I'm guessing I'm either misunderstanding the grammar or 反応 is being used in a way I'm not used to.
Full passage:

「違う、俺は魔王軍の関係者なんかじゃない！　テロリストでもない！　借金を背負わされた事は頭にきたし恨みにも思ったが、それでも、コロナタイトをワザと送りつけた訳じゃない！　いいか、魔道具をしっかり見とけよ！　言うぞ！　俺は、魔王軍の手先でも何でもない！」
俺が発したその言葉にベルは鳴らず、それを見た領主が言葉に詰まる。
セナもそれを見て、眉根を寄せて唇を嚙んだ。
魔道具での取り調べ結果を証拠にするというのなら、今こうして、俺の言葉が魔道具に反応していないのもまた証拠になる。
被害者である領主の一言が、逆に俺を助けた形になってしまった。
裁判長が、ゆっくりと首を振り。
「魔道具による噓の判別は、この様に曖昧なものなのです。これでは、魔道具の反応を理由とする検察官の主張は、証拠として認める訳にはいきませんね。流石に根拠が薄すぎる。よって。被告人、サトウカズマ。あなたへの嫌疑は不十分とみなし────」


I would think it's an error. It should be 俺の言葉に魔道具が反応していない.

Or 俺の言葉が魔道具を反応させていない. I'm sorry, but it's our rule to resolve a question based on typo like this as "closed".
